# Can anybody help me resolve these FWTS issues?

Tags: bios, reboot, acpi, firmware

See the list below. I have no clue where to start.

I ran firmware testsuitelive (USB). Some tests failed, which might explain the issues I'm having with my machine (constant reboot after shutdown or suspend, I assume these are ACPI issues).

I have the latest BIOS on my system.

Many thanks in advance for helping sort those out!

```
Results generated by fwts: Version V0.26.03 (Thu Dec 20 16:46:56 CST 2012).

Some of this work - Copyright (c) 1999 - 2010, Intel Corp. All rights reserved.
Some of this work - Copyright (c) 2010 - 2012, Canonical.

This test run on 12/10/13 at 09:33:10 on host Linux ubuntu 3.5.0-22-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Sat Jan
12 05:02:01 UTC 2013 x86_64.

Running tests: version bios_info oops mtrr acpiinfo klog csm microcode msr nx cpufreq maxfreq virt
maxreadreq crs aspm hpet_check dmi_decode smbios pnp pciirq mpcheck os2gap hda_audio bios32 ebda pcc
wmi osilinux apicedge method mcfg fan fadt dmar cstates checksum apicinstance acpitables syntaxcheck
wakealarm.

Gather kernel system information.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test 1 of 3: Gather kernel signature.
Signature: Ubuntu 3.5.0-22.34-generic 3.5.7.2

Test 2 of 3: Gather kernel system information.
Kernel Version: Linux version 3.5.0-22-generic (buildd@chindi05) (gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro
4.6.1-9ubuntu3) ) #34-Ubuntu SMP Sat Jan 12 05:02:01 UTC 2013

Test 3 of 3: Gather APCI driver version.
ACPI Version: 20120320

====================================================================================================
0 passed, 0 failed, 0 warnings, 0 aborted, 0 skipped, 3 info only.
====================================================================================================

Gather BIOS DMI information.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test 1 of 1: Gather BIOS DMI information
BIOS Vendor       : American Megatrends Inc.
BIOS Version      : P1.80
BIOS Release Date : 07/12/2013
Board Name        : B75 Pro3-M
Board Serial #    : 
Board Version     : 
Board Asset Tag   : 
Chassis Serial #  : To Be Filled By O.E.M.
Chassis Type      : 3
Chassis Vendor    : To Be Filled By O.E.M.
Chassis Version   : To Be Filled By O.E.M.
Chassic Asset Tag : To Be Filled By O.E.M.
Product Name      : To Be Filled By O.E.M.
Product Serial #  : To Be Filled By O.E.M.
Product UUID      : 00020003-0004-0005-0006-000700080009
Product Version   : To Be Filled By O.E.M.
System Vendor     : To Be Filled By O.E.M.

====================================================================================================
0 passed, 0 failed, 0 warnings, 0 aborted, 0 skipped, 1 info only.
====================================================================================================

MTRR validation.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MTRR overview
-------------
Reg 0: 0x0000000000000000 - 0x0000000400000000 ( 16384 MB)   Write-Back
Reg 1: 0x0000000400000000 - 0x0000000420000000 (   512 MB)   Write-Back
Reg 2: 0x00000000e0000000 - 0x0000000100000000 (   512 MB)   Uncached
Reg 3: 0x00000000d0000000 - 0x00000000e0000000 (   256 MB)   Uncached
Reg 4: 0x00000000cf800000 - 0x00000000d0000000 (     8 MB)   Uncached
Reg 5: 0x000000041f000000 - 0x0000000420000000 (    16 MB)   Uncached
Reg 6: 0x000000041e800000 - 0x000000041f000000 (     8 MB)   Uncached
Reg 7: 0x000000041e600000 - 0x000000041e800000 (     2 MB)   Uncached

Test 1 of 3: Validate the kernel MTRR IOMEM setup.
FAILED [MEDIUM] MTRRIncorrectAttr: Test 1, Memory range 0xe0000000 to 0xefffffff (0000:00:02.0) has
incorrect attribute Uncached Write-Back.
FAILED [MEDIUM] MTRRIncorrectAttr: Test 1, Memory range 0xf0000000 to 0xf0003fff (0000:03:00.0) has
incorrect attribute Uncached Write-Back.
FAILED [MEDIUM] MTRRIncorrectAttr: Test 1, Memory range 0xf0004000 to 0xf0004fff (0000:03:00.0) has
incorrect attribute Uncached Write-Back.
FAILED [MEDIUM] MTRRIncorrectAttr: Test 1, Memory range 0xf7800000 to 0xf7bfffff (0000:00:02.0) has
incorrect attribute Write-Back.
FAILED [MEDIUM] MTRRIncorrectAttr: Test 1, Memory range 0xf7c00000 to 0xf7c1ffff (0000:04:02.0) has
incorrect attribute Write-Back.
FAILED [MEDIUM] MTRRIncorrectAttr: Test 1, Memory range 0xf7c20000 to 0xf7c200ff (0000:04:02.0) has
incorrect attribute Write-Back.
FAILED [MEDIUM] MTRRIncorrectAttr: Test 1, Memory range 0xf7d00000 to 0xf7d001ff (0000:02:00.0) has
incorrect attribute Write-Back.
FAILED [MEDIUM] MTRRIncorrectAttr: Test 1, Memory range 0xf7e00000 to 0xf7e0ffff (0000:00:14.0) has
incorrect attribute Write-Back.
FAILED [MEDIUM] MTRRIncorrectAttr: Test 1, Memory range 0xf7e10000 to 0xf7e13fff (0000:00:1b.0) has
incorrect attribute Write-Back.
FAILED [MEDIUM] MTRRIncorrectAttr: Test 1, Memory range 0xf7e15000 to 0xf7e150ff (0000:00:1f.3) has
incorrect attribute Write-Back.
FAILED [MEDIUM] MTRRIncorrectAttr: Test 1, Memory range 0xf7e16000 to 0xf7e167ff (0000:00:1f.2) has
incorrect attribute Write-Back.
FAILED [MEDIUM] MTRRIncorrectAttr: Test 1, Memory range 0xf7e17000 to 0xf7e173ff (0000:00:1d.0) has
incorrect attribute Write-Back.
FAILED [MEDIUM] MTRRIncorrectAttr: Test 1, Memory range 0xf7e18000 to 0xf7e183ff (0000:00:1a.0) has
incorrect attribute Write-Back.
FAILED [MEDIUM] MTRRIncorrectAttr: Test 1, Memory range 0xf7e1b000 to 0xf7e1b00f (0000:00:16.0) has
incorrect attribute Write-Back.

Test 2 of 3: Validate the MTRR setup across all processors.
PASSED: Test 2, All processors have the a consistent MTRR setup.

Test 3 of 3: Check for AMD MtrrFixDramModEn being cleared by the BIOS.
SKIPPED: Test 3, CPU is not an AMD, cannot test.

====================================================================================================
1 passed, 14 failed, 0 warnings, 0 aborted, 1 skipped, 0 info only.
====================================================================================================

General ACPI information check.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test 1 of 3: Determine Kernel ACPI version.
Kernel ACPICA driver version: 20120320, supports ACPI 5.0

Test 2 of 3: Determine machines ACPI version.
FACP ACPI Version: 2.0 

Test 3 of 3: Determine AML compiler.
Determine the compiler used to generate the ACPI AML in the DSDT and SSDT.
Table DSDT, OEM ALASKA, created with INTL (Intel) compiler.
Table SSDT0, OEM Intel_, created with INTL (Intel) compiler.
Table SSDT1, OEM SataRe, created with INTL (Intel) compiler.
Table SSDT2, OEM PmRef, created with INTL (Intel) compiler.
Table SSDT3, OEM PmRef, created with INTL (Intel) compiler.

====================================================================================================
0 passed, 0 failed, 0 warnings, 0 aborted, 0 skipped, 3 info only.
====================================================================================================

Scan kernel log for errors and warnings.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test 1 of 1: Kernel log error check.
Kernel message: [ 0.067371] ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'

ADVICE: This is not exactly a failure but a warning from the kernel. The MSR_IA32_ENERGY_PERF_BIAS
was initialized and defaulted to a high performance bias setting. The kernel has detected this and
changed it down to a 'normal' bias setting.

FAILED [HIGH] KlogAcpiBadAmlCode: Test 1, HIGH Kernel message: [ 9.138069] ACPI Warning:
0x0000000000000460-0x000000000000047f SystemIO conflicts with Region \PMIO 1 (20120320
/utaddress-251)

ADVICE: ACPI AML intepreter has found some non-conforming AML code. This should be investigated and
fixed.

FAILED [HIGH] KlogAcpiBadAmlCode: Test 1, HIGH Kernel message: [ 9.138078] ACPI Warning:
0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042f SystemIO conflicts with Region \PMIO 1 (20120320
/utaddress-251)

ADVICE: ACPI AML intepreter has found some non-conforming AML code. This should be investigated and
fixed.

FAILED [HIGH] KlogAcpiBadAmlCode: Test 1, HIGH Kernel message: [ 9.138083] ACPI Warning:
0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000053f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPR2 1 (20120320
/utaddress-251)

ADVICE: ACPI AML intepreter has found some non-conforming AML code. This should be investigated and
fixed.

FAILED [HIGH] KlogAcpiBadAmlCode: Test 1, HIGH Kernel message: [ 9.138085] ACPI Warning:
0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000053f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 2 (20120320
/utaddress-251)

ADVICE: ACPI AML intepreter has found some non-conforming AML code. This should be investigated and
fixed.

Found 4 unique errors in kernel log.

====================================================================================================
0 passed, 4 failed, 0 warnings, 0 aborted, 0 skipped, 0 info only.
====================================================================================================

Check if system is using latest microcode.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cannot read microcode file /usr/share/misc/intel-microcode.dat.
Aborted test, initialisation failed.
====================================================================================================
0 passed, 0 failed, 0 warnings, 1 aborted, 0 skipped, 0 info only.
====================================================================================================

CPU frequency scaling tests (takes ~1-2 mins).
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test 1 of 1: CPU P-State Checks.
For each processor in the system, this test steps through the various frequency states (P-states)
that the BIOS advertises for the processor. For each processor/frequency combination, a quick
performance value is measured. The test then validates that:
  1) Each processor has the same number of frequency states
  2) Higher advertised frequencies have a higher performance
  3) No duplicate frequency values are reported by the BIOS
  4) Is BIOS wrongly doing Sw_All P-state coordination across cores
  5) Is BIOS wrongly doing Sw_Any P-state coordination across cores
CPU 0: 14 CPU frequency steps supported.
 Frequency | Relative Speed | Bogo loops
-----------+----------------+-----------
  2.95 GHz |     100.0 %    |    204373
  2.85 GHz |      96.6 %    |    197330
  2.75 GHz |      93.1 %    |    190280
  2.65 GHz |      89.7 %    |    183233
  2.55 GHz |      86.2 %    |    176181
  2.45 GHz |      82.8 %    |    169132
  2.35 GHz |      79.3 %    |    162082
  2.25 GHz |      75.9 %    |    155035
  2.15 GHz |      72.4 %    |    147988
  2.05 GHz |      69.0 %    |    140941
  1.95 GHz |      65.5 %    |    133890
  1.85 GHz |      62.1 %    |    126847
  1.75 GHz |      58.6 %    |    119799
  1.65 GHz |      55.2 %    |    112749

CPU 1: 14 CPU frequency steps supported.
 Frequency | Relative Speed | Bogo loops
-----------+----------------+-----------
  2.95 GHz |     100.0 %    |    204374
  2.85 GHz |      96.6 %    |    197326
  2.75 GHz |      93.1 %    |    190275
  2.65 GHz |      89.7 %    |    183227
  2.55 GHz |      86.2 %    |    176175
  2.45 GHz |      82.8 %    |    169123
  2.35 GHz |      83.8 %    |    171200
  2.25 GHz |      75.9 %    |    155028
  2.15 GHz |      72.4 %    |    147983
  2.05 GHz |      69.0 %    |    140934
  1.95 GHz |      65.5 %    |    133863
  1.85 GHz |      62.1 %    |    126841
  1.75 GHz |      58.6 %    |    119792
  1.65 GHz |      55.2 %    |    112744

FAILED [MEDIUM] CPUFreqSlowerOnCPU: Test 1, Supposedly higher frequency 2.45 GHz is slower (169123
bogo loops) than frequency 2.45 GHz (171200 bogo loops) on CPU 1.
PASSED: Test 1, P-state coordination done by Hardware.

====================================================================================================
1 passed, 1 failed, 0 warnings, 0 aborted, 0 skipped, 0 info only.
====================================================================================================

Checks firmware has set PCI Express MaxReadReq to a higher value on non-motherboard devices.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test 1 of 1: Check firmware settings MaxReadReq for PCI Express devices.
MaxReadReq for pci://00:00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio
Controller (rev 04) is low (128) [Audio device].
FAILED [LOW] LowMaxReadReq: Test 1, 1 devices have low MaxReadReq settings. Firmware may have
configured these too low.

ADVICE: The MaxReadRequest size is set too low and will affect performance. It will provide
excellent bus sharing at the cost of bus data transfer rates. Although not a critical issue, it may
be worth considering setting the MaxReadRequest size to 256 or 512 to increase throughput on the PCI
Express bus. Some drivers (for example the Brocade Fibre Channel driver) allow one to override the
firmware settings. Where possible, this BIOS configuration setting is worth increasing it a little
more for better performance at a small reduction of bus sharing.


====================================================================================================
0 passed, 1 failed, 0 warnings, 0 aborted, 0 skipped, 0 info only.
====================================================================================================

PCIe ASPM check.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test 1 of 2: PCIe ASPM ACPI test.
PCIe ASPM is not controlled by Linux kernel.

ADVICE: BIOS reports that Linux kernel should not modify ASPM settings that BIOS configured. It can
be intentional because hardware vendors identified some capability bugs between the motherboard and
the add-on cards.


Test 2 of 2: PCIe ASPM registers test.
WARNING: Test 2, RP 00h:1Ch.04h L0s not enabled.
WARNING: Test 2, RP 00h:1Ch.04h L1 not enabled.
WARNING: Test 2, Device 02h:00h.00h L0s not enabled.

ADVICE: The ASPM L0s low power Link state is optimized for short entry and exit latencies, while
providing substantial power savings. Disabling L0s of a PCIe device may increases power consumption,
and will impact the battery life of a mobile system.


ADVICE: The ASPM L1 low power Link state is optimized for maximum power savings with longer entry
and exit latencies. Disabling L1 of a PCIe device may increases power consumption, and will impact
the battery life of a mobile system significantly.

PASSED: Test 2, PCIe ASPM setting matched was matched.
WARNING: Test 2, RP 00h:1Ch.05h L0s not enabled.
WARNING: Test 2, RP 00h:1Ch.05h L1 not enabled.
WARNING: Test 2, Device 03h:00h.00h L0s not enabled.
WARNING: Test 2, Device 03h:00h.00h L1 not enabled.

ADVICE: The ASPM L0s low power Link state is optimized for short entry and exit latencies, while
providing substantial power savings. Disabling L0s of a PCIe device may increases power consumption,
and will impact the battery life of a mobile system.


ADVICE: The ASPM L1 low power Link state is optimized for maximum power savings with longer entry
and exit latencies. Disabling L1 of a PCIe device may increases power consumption, and will impact
the battery life of a mobile system significantly.

PASSED: Test 2, PCIe ASPM setting matched was matched.
PASSED: Test 2, PCIe ASPM setting matched was matched.

====================================================================================================
3 passed, 0 failed, 7 warnings, 0 aborted, 0 skipped, 0 info only.
====================================================================================================

Test DMI/SMBIOS tables for errors.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test 1 of 1: Test DMI/SMBIOS tables for errors.
PASSED: Test 1, Entry @ 0x000ee880 'BIOS Information (Type 0)'
FAILED [MEDIUM] DMIBadDefault: Test 1, String index 0x01 in table entry 'System Information (Type
1)' @ 0x000ee8c3, field 'Manufacturer', offset 0x04 has a default value 'To Be Filled By O.E.M.' and
probably has not been updated by the BIOS vendor.

ADVICE: The DMI table contains data which is clearly been left in a default setting and not been
configured for this machine. Somebody has probably forgotten to define this field and it basically
means this field is effectively useless. Note that the kernel uses this field so it probably should
be corrected to ensure the kernel is using sane values.

FAILED [MEDIUM] DMIBadDefault: Test 1, String index 0x02 in table entry 'System Information (Type
1)' @ 0x000ee8c3, field 'Product Name', offset 0x05 has a default value 'To Be Filled By O.E.M.' and
probably has not been updated by the BIOS vendor.

ADVICE: The DMI table contains data which is clearly been left in a default setting and not been
configured for this machine. Somebody has probably forgotten to define this field and it basically
means this field is effectively useless. Note that the kernel uses this field so it probably should
be corrected to ensure the kernel is using sane values.

FAILED [MEDIUM] DMIBadDefault: Test 1, String index 0x03 in table entry 'System Information (Type
1)' @ 0x000ee8c3, field 'Version', offset 0x06 has a default value 'To Be Filled By O.E.M.' and
probably has not been updated by the BIOS vendor.

ADVICE: The DMI table contains data which is clearly been left in a default setting and not been
configured for this machine. Somebody has probably forgotten to define this field and it basically
means this field is effectively useless. Note that the kernel uses this field so it probably should
be corrected to ensure the kernel is using sane values.

FAILED [MEDIUM] DMIBadDefault: Test 1, String index 0x04 in table entry 'System Information (Type
1)' @ 0x000ee8c3, field 'Serial Number', offset 0x07 has a default value 'To Be Filled By O.E.M.'
and probably has not been updated by the BIOS vendor.

ADVICE: The DMI table contains data which is clearly been left in a default setting and not been
configured for this machine. Somebody has probably forgotten to define this field and it basically
means this field is effectively useless. Note that the kernel uses this field so it probably should
be corrected to ensure the kernel is using sane values.

FAILED [LOW] DMIBadDefault: Test 1, String index 0x05 in table entry 'System Information (Type 1)' @
0x000ee8c3, field 'SKU Number', offset 0x19 has a default value 'To Be Filled By O.E.M.' and
probably has not been updated by the BIOS vendor.

ADVICE: The DMI table contains data which is clearly been left in a default setting and not been
configured for this machine. Somebody has probably forgotten to define this field and it basically
means this field is effectively useless, however the kernel does not use this data so the issue is
fairly low.

FAILED [LOW] DMIBadDefault: Test 1, String index 0x06 in table entry 'System Information (Type 1)' @
0x000ee8c3, field 'Family', offset 0x1a has a default value 'To Be Filled By O.E.M.' and probably
has not been updated by the BIOS vendor.

ADVICE: The DMI table contains data which is clearly been left in a default setting and not been
configured for this machine. Somebody has probably forgotten to define this field and it basically
means this field is effectively useless, however the kernel does not use this data so the issue is
fairly low.


ADVICE: It may be worth checking against section 7.2 of the System Management BIOS (SMBIOS)
Reference Specification.

PASSED: Test 1, Entry @ 0x000ee969 'Base Board Information (Type 2)'
FAILED [MEDIUM] DMIBadDefault: Test 1, String index 0x01 in table entry 'Chassis Information (Type
3)' @ 0x000ee9e7, field 'Manufacturer', offset 0x04 has a default value 'To Be Filled By O.E.M.' and
probably has not been updated by the BIOS vendor.

ADVICE: The DMI table contains data which is clearly been left in a default setting and not been
configured for this machine. Somebody has probably forgotten to define this field and it basically
means this field is effectively useless. Note that the kernel uses this field so it probably should
be corrected to ensure the kernel is using sane values.

FAILED [MEDIUM] DMIBadDefault: Test 1, String index 0x02 in table entry 'Chassis Information (Type
3)' @ 0x000ee9e7, field 'Version', offset 0x06 has a default value 'To Be Filled By O.E.M.' and
probably has not been updated by the BIOS vendor.

ADVICE: The DMI table contains data which is clearly been left in a default setting and not been
configured for this machine. Somebody has probably forgotten to define this field and it basically
means this field is effectively useless. Note that the kernel uses this field so it probably should
be corrected to ensure the kernel is using sane values.

FAILED [MEDIUM] DMIBadDefault: Test 1, String index 0x03 in table entry 'Chassis Information (Type
3)' @ 0x000ee9e7, field 'Serial Number', offset 0x07 has a default value 'To Be Filled By O.E.M.'
and probably has not been updated by the BIOS vendor.

ADVICE: The DMI table contains data which is clearly been left in a default setting and not been
configured for this machine. Somebody has probably forgotten to define this field and it basically
means this field is effectively useless. Note that the kernel uses this field so it probably should
be corrected to ensure the kernel is using sane values.

FAILED [MEDIUM] DMIBadDefault: Test 1, String index 0x04 in table entry 'Chassis Information (Type
3)' @ 0x000ee9e7, field 'Asset Tag', offset 0x08 has a default value 'To Be Filled By O.E.M.' and
probably has not been updated by the BIOS vendor.

ADVICE: The DMI table contains data which is clearly been left in a default setting and not been
configured for this machine. Somebody has probably forgotten to define this field and it basically
means this field is effectively useless. Note that the kernel uses this field so it probably should
be corrected to ensure the kernel is using sane values.


ADVICE: It may be worth checking against section 7.4 of the System Management BIOS (SMBIOS)
Reference Specification.

PASSED: Test 1, Entry @ 0x000eea71 'System Slot Information (Type 9)'
PASSED: Test 1, Entry @ 0x000eea88 'System Slot Information (Type 9)'
PASSED: Test 1, Entry @ 0x000eea9f 'System Slot Information (Type 9)'
PASSED: Test 1, Entry @ 0x000eeab7 'System Slot Information (Type 9)'
FAILED [MEDIUM] DMIBadDefault: Test 1, String index 0x01 in table entry 'OEM Strings (Type 11)' @
0x000eeacf, field 'String 1', offset 0x04 has a default value 'To Be Filled By O.E.M.' and probably
has not been updated by the BIOS vendor.

ADVICE: The DMI table contains data which is clearly been left in a default setting and not been
configured for this machine. Somebody has probably forgotten to define this field and it basically
means this field is effectively useless. Note that the kernel uses this field so it probably should
be corrected to ensure the kernel is using sane values.


ADVICE: It may be worth checking against section 7.12 of the System Management BIOS (SMBIOS)
Reference Specification.

PASSED: Test 1, Entry @ 0x000eeaec 'System Boot Information (Type 32)'
PASSED: Test 1, Entry @ 0x000eeb02 'Cache Information (Type 7)'
PASSED: Test 1, Entry @ 0x000eeb26 'Cache Information (Type 7)'
PASSED: Test 1, Entry @ 0x000eeb4a 'Cache Information (Type 7)'
PASSED: Test 1, Entry @ 0x000eeb6e 'Physical Memory Array (Type 16)'
PASSED: Test 1, Entry @ 0x000eeb87 'Processor Information (Type 4)'
PASSED: Test 1, Entry @ 0x000eec11 'Memory Device (Type 17)'
PASSED: Test 1, Entry @ 0x000eec6d 'Memory Device (Type 17)'
PASSED: Test 1, Entry @ 0x000eecd2 'Memory Device Mapped Address (Type 20)'
PASSED: Test 1, Entry @ 0x000eecf7 'Memory Device (Type 17)'
PASSED: Test 1, Entry @ 0x000eed53 'Memory Device (Type 17)'
PASSED: Test 1, Entry @ 0x000eedb8 'Memory Device Mapped Address (Type 20)'
PASSED: Test 1, Entry @ 0x000eeddd 'Memory Array Mapped Address (Type 19)'
PASSED: Test 1, Entry @ 0x000eedfe 'Unknown (Type 129)'
PASSED: Test 1, Entry @ 0x000eee1f 'Unknown (Type 130)'
PASSED: Test 1, Entry @ 0x000eee35 'Unknown (Type 131)'
PASSED: Test 1, Entry @ 0x000eee77 'End of Table (Type 127)'

====================================================================================================
23 passed, 11 failed, 0 warnings, 0 aborted, 0 skipped, 0 info only.
====================================================================================================

Check MultiProcessor Tables.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test 1 of 9: Check MP header.
PASSED: Test 1, MP header looks sane.

Test 2 of 9: Check MP CPU entries.
PASSED: Test 2, All 2 CPU entries look sane.

Test 3 of 9: Check MP Bus entries.
PASSED: Test 3, All 6 Bus Entries looked sane.

Test 4 of 9: Check MP IO APIC entries.
PASSED: Test 4, All 1 IO APIC Entries look sane.

Test 5 of 9: Check MP IO Interrupt entries.
PASSED: Test 5, All 66 IO Interrupt Entries look sane.

Test 6 of 9: Check MP Local Interrupt entries.
PASSED: Test 6, All 2 Local Interrupt Entries look sane.

Test 7 of 9: Check MP System Address entries.
FAILED [MEDIUM] MPSysAddrSpaceAddrLength: Test 7, System Address Space Mapping Entry 3 (@0x000fd7a8)
has a zero sized Address Length.
FAILED [MEDIUM] MPSysAddrSpaceAddrLength: Test 7, System Address Space Mapping Entry 4 (@0x000fd7bc)
has a zero sized Address Length.

Test 8 of 9: Check MP Bus Hierarchy entries.
PASSED: Test 8, All 1 Bus Hierarchy Entries look sane.

Test 9 of 9: Check MP Compatible Bus Address Space entries.
PASSED: Test 9, All 2 Compatible Bus Address Space Entries look sane.

====================================================================================================
8 passed, 2 failed, 0 warnings, 0 aborted, 0 skipped, 0 info only.
====================================================================================================


ACPI DSDT Method Semantic Tests.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FADT Preferred PM profile indicates this is not a Mobile Platform.
Failed to install global event handler.
Test 9 of 139: Check _STR (String).
FAILED [MEDIUM] MethodReturnBadType: Test 9, Method \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.TPM_._STR did not return
ACPI_TYPE_STRING.
PASSED: Test 9, \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.TPM_._STR correctly acquired and released locks 3 times.
FAILED [MEDIUM] MethodReturnBadType: Test 9, Method \_SB_.PCI0.ITPM._STR did not return
ACPI_TYPE_STRING.
PASSED: Test 9, \_SB_.PCI0.ITPM._STR correctly acquired and released locks 3 times.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there were motherboard issues. Replacing the hardware fixed my issues.